# Is there a way to take a specific character input from the user and make so that an error occurs if that specific character is not entered

Tags: java

I am currently trying to get user input of a character to state whether they are L for local or I for international.By having them input a specific character however the issue i am running into is that for the character input I can input more than just a character for exapmle a string or an integer when it should just be a character

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double electrical_e_cost = 850.53;
    double mechanical_eng_cost =895.25;
    double petroleum_eng_cost = 450.67;
    double computer_eng_cost = 921.14;   
    int studentcount = 10;
    int idnumber []=new int[10];
    String[] studentname = new String[2];
    int courseamount[]=new int [10];
    char stype []=new char[10];
    char coursetype []=new char[10];
    
    
     
    for(int i=0; i<idnumber.length;i++)
   {  
     
       System.out.println("Enter Name ");
       studentname[i]=input.next();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter Student ID number ");
        idnumber[i]= input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Please say wheather you are an internationanal or Local student by typing I or L respectively");
        char t=input.next().charAt(0);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the course type either E,M,P,C ");
         coursetype[i] =input.next().charAt(0);
        
        System.out.println("Please enter The course amount  ");
        courseamount[i]= input.nextInt();
        
        
        
                 
   } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Validate yourself the input:

```
System.out.print("Please say wheather you are an internationanal or Local student by typing I or L respectively");
char t=input.next().charAt(0);
while(!t.equals("L") && !t.equals("I")) {
       System.out.print("Please say wheather you are an internationanal or Local student by typing I or L respectively");
       t=input.next().charAt(0);
}
```